# SSL certificate for website - no legal company name?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I am launching my own social website and need SSL for the user login section. To get the SSL they require the CSR key, which requires an organization name, and this name it is mentioned should be legally registered in your state.

I don't have a company and have no plans to open one unless my project kicks off and I see future growth, so if I use my website name as the organization name (which has no offline existence except the website), will I get into trouble?

Of course at the same time I don't want to use my name on the SSL but want to use the company name.

Answer (score 15):

I just used my domain name as the Organization name. They'll usually accept that.

Comment: How the hell do you only have 11 up votes. Life saver for me! ATB Steve

Answer (score 4):

the Organisation name doesnt have to be strictly accurate unless its organisation validated, for basic domain validation certificates, they only validate that you do indeed have control of the domain, any value will work in the organisation field in this case, its generally simplest to use the domain as @bahamat says or make up an organisation name or even use your own name again

on a domain validated certificate the organisation that you entered in the CSR generally is never shown